# Sql get sum row by row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have one table it looks like below

```
ID | PName | Price
___+_______+______
1  |some   |2000
2  |some   |3000
3  |some   |250
```

now i need to query for get following result

```
ID | PName | Price  |Total Price
___+_______+________+____________
1  |some   |2000    |2000
2  |some   |3000    |5000
3  |some   |250     |5250


Total Price= Price + Total Price
```

How to get above result using sql query

Comment: sql server 2014

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You seem to want a cumulative sum.  This is supported as:

```
select t.*,
       sum(price) over (order by id) as total_price
from t;
```

SQL Server has supported this ANSI-standard syntax since SQL Server 2012.

In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.price)
        from t t2
        where t2.id <= t.id
       ) as total_price
from t;
```

EDIT:

As John suggests, if you want a separate sum for each `pname`, then the syntax would be:

```
select t.*,
       sum(t.price) over (partition by p.name order by t.id) as total_price
from t;
```

Comment: Not specified in the question, but perhaps PARTITION by PName  ?

Comment: Thanks For every one who helped me @Gordon